# RecursionError occurs with every attempted Anaconda package update / installation

Tags: windows-10, installation, anaconda, runtime-error, installation-package

I recently have seen the same 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded' message when I attempt to update existing packages or when installing new packages. For example, conda install -c anaconda impyla, conda update conda, conda update anaconda, etc...

Anyone have any ideas to solve this? Thanks!

Here is the full error code for 'conda install -c anaconda impyla' specifically:

(base) C:\Users\kner7001>conda install -c anaconda impyla
Solving environment: failed

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 789, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 11, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 236, in install
    force_reinstall=context.force,
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 504, in solve_for_transaction
    force_remove, force_reinstall)
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 437, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 218, in solve_final_state
    _, inconsistent_dists = r.bad_installed(solution, ())
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 731, in bad_installed
    C = r2.gen_clauses()
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 509, in gen_clauses
    C.Require(C.Or, nkey, self.push_MatchSpec(C, ms))
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 481, in push_MatchSpec
    m = C.from_name(self.push_MatchSpec(C, ms2))
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 481, in push_MatchSpec
    m = C.from_name(self.push_MatchSpec(C, ms2))
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 481, in push_MatchSpec
    m = C.from_name(self.push_MatchSpec(C, ms2))
  [Previous line repeated 966 more times]
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 480, in push_MatchSpec
    ms2 = MatchSpec(track_features=tf) if tf else MatchSpec(nm)
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\models\match_spec.py", line 76, in __call__
    return super(MatchSpecType, cls).__call__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\models\match_spec.py", line 178, in __init__
    self._match_components = self._build_components(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\conda\models\match_spec.py", line 365, in _build_components
    return frozendict(_make(key, value) for key, value in iteritems(kwargs))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

`$ C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\Scripts\conda install -c anaconda impyla`

environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\kner7001
                     PATH=C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda;C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\Library\mingw-w6
                          4\bin;C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\kner7001\Ana
                          conda\Library\bin;C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Users\kner7001
                          \Anaconda\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Nielsen\SYBASE\15.7\dll\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
                          Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
                          Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common
                          Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\WINDO
                          WS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wi
                          ndowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
                          Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\P
                          uTTY\;C:\Users\kner7001\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Progra
                          m Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
         PYTHONIOENCODING=1252
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=
            SSL_CERT_FILE=

```
 active environment : base
active env location : C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda
        shell level : 1
   user config file : C:\Users\kner7001\.condarc
```

populated config files : C:\Users\kner7001.condarc
          conda version : 4.4.10
    conda-build version : 3.4.1
         python version : 3.6.4.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\kner7001\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\kner7001\Anaconda\envs
                          C:\Users\kner7001\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\kner7001.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.4.10 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False